# Replace Twitter Bootstrap Background Color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using twitter bootstrap and I wanna set my page background-color to **#f8f8f9**. But I think the twitter bootstrap default white background is getting in the way.

I read and tried the methods in these as well:

[How to change twitter bootstrap background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456605/how-to-change-twitter-bootstrap-background-color)

[How to change the default background color white to something else in twitter boostrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768891/how-to-change-the-default-background-color-white-to-something-else-in-twitter-bo)

[assign background color in twitter bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618772/assign-background-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

I tried

```
body{ background-color: #f8f8f9 !important};
```

in an external CSS file and inline  as well. But none worked.

Any idea how to overcome this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: the code shown should work, but it has to be applied after all bootstrap css files

Comment: check your external line path, it should be included after bootstrap

Comment: add a class to body and try like `body.classname{ background-color: #f8f8f9 !important};`

Comment: Share the shortest code necessary to reproduce it ! Upload your website somewhere or share a complete Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use Less. In there, it's just a color variable that needs to be changed. Then, compile it again and your new background color should apply.

If you are not sure where to begin, this generator should help you: http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com

Answer (score 0):

your Code work well,color with Hex ID `#f8f8f9` is what you see after run code.

> http://www.color-hex.com/color/f8f8f9

I offer try this code and see work or not?

```
body {

       background-color: #3b3ba9 !important;
}
```

if work well so your code is ok, else find css rule that overlap this rule.